# Reverse Lookup field Update

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, designer-workflow, lookup-column

I have a lookup field which has 2 additional fields (all coming from List 1) which appear in List 2. Field 1, Field 2 and Status. Field 1 is the primary lookup, field 2 and Status just show the relevant data in relation to the selection from Field 1. I am wondering if its possible that when List 2 updates to a certain Status that the "Status" field in List 1 also updates to the same status.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Dee

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online? You can possibly do this using custom list form or workflow/power automate.

Comment: Hi, yes I am using SharePoint online. Just trying to figure out how to link the data in the workflow? So it matches the Status to the specific lookup data in List one. I'm very much a newbie to this!!! If you have any ideas I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Are you trying to do this using SharePoint designer workflow or power automate? The Idea is you can get the item ID of list 1 in List 2 workflow by using lookup. and based on your conditions and the list 1 item ID, you can change the status in list 1.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, I'd be using SP Designer, I think I have it worked out in my head I'll give it a shot and let you know!!! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Great. Write a workflow on list 2 on item change event-->Add If condition to check it the status is changed-->If changed then update item in list 1 using lookup ID.

Comment: Ganesh thanks so much this defiantly gives me a good direction!!! I'll let you know how it goes - thanks so much for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments above, in order to achieve this you can get the item ID of list 1 in workflow (added on List 2) by using lookup and based on your conditions & the list 1 item ID, you can change the status in list 1.

Here is the rough flow:

1. Create a on list 2 on item change event.
2. Get the item id of list 1 from lookup column in list 2.
3. Add If condition to check it the status is changed.
4. If status is changed then update item in list 1 using lookup ID and "Update item" action.